# powershell returning 1 single element instead of array

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have followed different posts on the web to fix this issue but my code still returns a single element insteaf of array. My code below:

```
Add-PSSnapin -Name VeeamPSSnapIn -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    $sessionVMSummary = @()
    $bkJobs = get-vbrjob | foreach {
        $session = $_.findlastsession()
        if (($session -ne $NULL) -and ($_.isScheduleEnabled -eq $TRUE)) {
            # Get session details
            $sessionDocument = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                "Name" = $session.JobName
                "Result" = $session.Result.toString()
                "ObjectStatus" = @()
            }
            [Veeam.Backup.Core.CBackupTaskSession]::GetByJobSession($session.id) | foreach {
                $Info = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    "Start Time" = $_.Progress.StartTime
                    "End Time" = $_.Progress.StopTime
                    "Duration" = $_.Progress.Duration
                }
                $sessionDocument.ObjectStatus += $Info
            }
            $sessionVMSummary += $sessionDocument
        }
    }

    return $sessionVMSummary
```

Question 1: How can I make $sessionVMSummary to return an array whith 1 element?
Question 2: How can I make my code more efficient from the grammar point of view?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the comma operator to wrap your array in another array e.g.:

```
return ,$sessionVMSummary
```

Comment: thank you @KeithHill. This will return an ArrayList and I need [Object]. The thing is ConvertTo-JSON of ArrayList will only return an object instead of an array... weird

Comment: Then just call `ToArray()` on the ArrayList e.g. `return ,($sessionVMSummary.ToArray())`